# Retrieve DTO with list inside using JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is there a way to get such object within a single query in JPA?

```
data class PartcipantsDTO(
   val max: Int,
   val list: List<ParticipantCardDTO>
) // this one

ParticipantCardDTO(
   val id: Long,
   val name: String
)
```

Assuming that entities looks like:

```
@Entity
ParticipantEntity(
   @Id id: Long,
   name: String,
   @ManyToOne event: EventEntity
)

@Entity
EventEntity(
   @Id id: Long,
   @OneToMany participants: List<Long>
)
```

To search by EventEntity id was trying query like:

```
SELECT new com.***.ParticipantsDTO(
   e.max,
   SELECT new ParticipantCardDTO(
      p.id,
      p.name
   )
)
FROM ParticipantEntity p, EventEntity e
WHERE p.id IN e.participants AND e.id = :id
```

But it doesn't work

I do know that it can be done with 2 separate queries, but I want to avoid opening 2 connections due to inefficiency

Comment: you can query data with jpa projections and then you can map that list of projection to list of dto. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces

Comment: That's not possible with JPA.

Comment: When you say `max`, are you referring to the number of participants in an event?

Comment: Yes, but that's just a dummy object, the main thing is how to map records to list elements on fly

Answer (score 1):

you can get ParticipantEntity using JPA, then map it and its participants list to DTO in Java, hibernate will handle its properties.

this is because hibernate have cache and handles performance issues itself.

Comment: I agree. Let hibernate handle the number of open connections it needs to make.